# Retrieving frequency of N-grams specified by their field content

Tags: lucene, field, frequency, n-gram

Is there a way to retrieve the frequency of N-grams that match a specific field content in a Lucene 4.7.2 index?

I want to find and count all occurences of 3-grams, where the first token is an adjective(JJ), the second token is an adjective(JJ) and the third token is a noun(NN). This POS information is contained in a field called postag.

I thought of a query using an IndexSearcher `postag:"JJ JJ NN"` but I'm not sure about how to use the result to count the occurences.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Are you trying to get a count of the number of documents that contain that pattern?  Or the number of time that pattern is found within a document?

Comment: Your second mention is the one with the highest priority, but I need to implement both functions.